# Raspberry pi's local IP keeps changing. What are the solutions?

Tags: static-ip

It keeps changing beetween 10.0.0.1, 10.0.0.2, 10.0.0.3 etc. Is there a way to solve this without giving raspberry pi a static address? Because I ssh to the raspberry pi, or visit it on my browser, and it's slightly annoying to keep finding and changing the addresses. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is most likely due to your DHCP server being misconfigured. Do you have access to the DHCP server?

Comment: Once you get your DHCP server sorted, [here's an answer that might help with keeping the same IP address.](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/114405/83790)

Comment: @Seamus It's my router.

Comment: You should log into the router, and have a look at the DHCP configuration. You can also follow the proposal in [this answer.](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/114405/83790) Edit your `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` and add a line: `inform 10.0.0.25` (or whatever address you choose). This should keep your IP address constant, but still report it to the router/DHCP server - so it's always in the list of leases.

Answer (score 2):

This shouldn't happen with a properly configured DHCP server.

You can either reserve an IP Address in your router OR request the DHCP server to assign one.
E.g. the following in `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` will request an address on wlan0.

```
interface wlan0
request 10.0.0.99
```

NOTE This will only work if you request an IP Address **within the range managed by the DHCP server** which is available, otherwise the DHCP server will allocate an address as normal.

See [How to set up networking/WiFi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

Comment: Thank you, will try it out. It's just a router in my flat I am renting.