# Unable to ping or ssh into Raspberry Pi zero w from a Windows 8.1 PC but could successfully ping & ssh into it via a Windows 10 PC on the same network

Tags: ssh, pi-zero, pi-zero-w, raspberry-pi-os-buster, ping

I have a Pi Zero w.

it has been set up with a standard rasbpian imager and OS and latest files off the OEM website.

the boot drive also has an ssh file and a wpa_supplicant.conf file with necessary network credentials.

The first time I tried to ping it from my windows 8.1 PC, it returned that "ping request could not find host raspberrypi.local. please check the name and try again".

when I tried it again on another Windows 10 PC on the same network it went through flawlessly and I went on to run it through a standard config and set up a static IP address after which Pi-Hole was successfully set up and deployed.

I still face the issue of being unable to ping it from my windows 8.1 PC.

I have also downloaded the appropriate ssh files and added the directory to the path environment variable.

I've tried a lot of forums and am running out of options.

Comment: Try to access it using the IP address.

Comment: This question does not appear to be specific to the Raspberry Pi. As you've phrased the question, it seems clear the issue is **not** with the RPi, but rather your Windows machine. If you've got evidence to the contrary, please edit your question to add it. Otherwise, your question may be closed as "off topic".

Comment: Windows 8 doesn't have mDNS support!

Answer (score 1):

Your question is almost certainly off-topic, but here's something that ***may*** explain the difference in outcomes between your Win 10 & Win 8 PCs:

Briefly, it's called [*"Zero Configuration Networking"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking). I say it ***may*** explain the difference because I know very little about Windows, so this is more speculation, rather than an answer based on direct knowledge.

That said, I recall hearing/reading that Windows did not support *"Zero Configuration Networking"* out-of-the-box - it required the addition of some software (Apple's `Bonjour` maybe?). Perhaps it's the case that your older Win 8 doesn't support ZCN, but the newer Win 10 does? Try an Internet search to get further details.

I also suspect that @rtaft's comment/suggestion may resolve your issue - but perhaps at the expense of creating another issue! ***What am I talking about?*** We get a lot of questions here from people who attempt to set up a fixed IP address, but bungle it because they fail to read the documentation (`man dhcpcd` and `man dhcpcd-conf`). Please don't make that mistake; there's very [seldom a sound reason for setting up a fixed IP](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/115930/83790), but if you do it, please read the docs & **do it correctly**.